# Azure Storage account creation takes lot time

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

I have a windows Azure account with 6 months plan for cloud service and database. I have create cloud service and sql azure database and they were created within some minutes. I have also created a storage service and its status is creating for last 16 hours. I have created all these instances for south east Asia region. Is this normal for there is some issue.

I am new to Azure please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you this is not normal. My experience, creating storage account do takes longer than creating cloud service and sql database. But should be around seconds to minutes. Your 16 hours is unusual.

Did you meet this problem every storage account you created? Or just this one? I would suggest you create another storage account rather than waiting for this one is done.

Hope this helps.

Comment: When I add second account, the first one is completed with Online status. Also My second account takes only 1 min 
Thanks for help.